# TypeORM - Get data from many-to-many relationship

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

I've got 2 tables (News, Tags) with a relationship like this:

- 1 news can have many tags
- 1 tags can belong to many news

This is how I implemented their relationship:

News:

```
@Entity({ name: "news" })
export  class News extends Serializable {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment')
  news_id: number;

  @Column({name: "title", type: "varchar", length: 300})
  title: string;

  @Column({name: "content", type: "varchar", length: 5000})
  content: string;

  @Column({name: "create_date"})
  create_date: Date;

  @ManyToMany(() => Tags)
  @JoinTable()
  tagsnews: Tags[]
}
```

Tags:

```
@Entity({ name: "tags" })
export  class Tags extends Serializable {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment')
  tag_id: number;

  @Column({name: "name", type: "varchar", length: 300})
  name: string;
}
```

Using ManyToMany will create a table 'news_tagsnews_tags' that stores data like this:

[image]

Everything's ok but when I want to fetch a news's data and its tags:

```
dataObject = await getRepository(News).createQueryBuilder("news")
.leftJoinAndSelect("news.tagsnews", "tags") 
.where("news.news_id = :newsid", {newsid: params.news_id})
.getRawMany();
```

The result returns on many rows instead of 1 row, just like this:

```
  RowDataPacket {
    news_news_id: 1,
    news_title: 'Essence of Paris 1',
    news_create_date: 2021-10-08T04:58:31.000Z,
    tags_tag_id: 3,
    tags_name: 'france',
  },
  RowDataPacket {
    news_news_id: 1,
    news_title: 'Essence of Paris 1',
    news_create_date: 2021-10-08T04:58:31.000Z,
    tags_tag_id: 3,
    tags_name: 'travel',
  },
  RowDataPacket {
    news_news_id: 1,
    news_title: 'Essence of Paris 1',
    news_create_date: 2021-10-08T04:58:31.000Z,
    tags_tag_id: 3,
    tags_name: 'beautiful',
  }
]
```

What I want is something like this:

```
  RowDataPacket {
    news_news_id: 1,
    news_title: 'Essence of Paris 1',
    news_create_date: 2021-10-08T04:58:31.000Z,
    tags_tag_id: 3,
    tags: [{
        tag_id: 1,
        tag_name: france
        }, {
        tag_id: 2,
        tag_name: travel
        }, {
        tag_id: 3,
        tag_name: beautiful
        }
    ]
  }
]
```

I changed to `getRawOne()` but it doesn't help at all, it returns only 1 first record. Can someone help me on this matter?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `getMany()` instead of `.getRawMany()`, it works for me !

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).